# Python super override object name

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, super

I'm trying to extend a framework, I have something like this:

```
class A(object):
    def test(self):
        print(1)


class B(object):
    def method(self):
        a = A()
        a.test()


class CustomA(A):
    def test(self):
        print(2)


class C(B):

    def method(self):
        A = CustomA
        super(C, self).method()

c = C()
c.method()
```

Classes A and B are from the framework.

I want to edit this test() from A, and make C use this new method.

In this code, for example, how can I make my code print 2 instead of 1?

**[Update]**

This was just a simple example. I want to extend [this class](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/settings.py#L962). So instead of create a `SettingsPanel`, create a `CustomSettingsPanel`

But the problem is that I'll need to do it with a lot of classes, so I just want a way to make python always use `CustomSettingsPanel` and not `SettingsPanel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to approach this problem.

If you can edit `B`, then you could refactor it so that instead of a hard dependency on `A`, have it accept a parameter in the `___init___` to allow one to specify the class to instantiate.  Something like:

```
class B(object):
    def __init___(self, clazz=A):
        self.__clazz = clazz
    def method(self):
        a = self.__clazz()
        a.test()

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__(CustomA)
```

If you can't edit `B`, then I'd suggest wrapping it in an Adapter, have your code interact through that class (rather than `B` or `C`) and then manage the complexity of the `A` vs `CustomA` choice there in the adapter via a flag parameter:

```
class ABCAdapter(object):
    USE_CLASS_A = 0
    USE_CLASS_CUSTOMA = 1

    def __init__(self, test_class=USE_CLASS_A):
        if test_class = USE_CLASS_A:
            self.a_instance = A()
        elif test_class = USE_CLASS_CUSTOMA:
            self.a_instance = CustomA()

    def method(self):
        self.a_instance.test()
```

Could also look into other object creational patterns (factories, etc).  All depends on your constraints and what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call super in C. You are trying to override B's method.

```
class A(object):
    def test(self):
        print(1)


class B(object):
    def method(self):
        a = A()
        a.test()


class CustomA(A):
    def test(self):
        print(2)


class C(B):
    def method(self):
        A = CustomA()
        A.test()

c = C()
c.method()
```

Comment: This was just a simple example. I want to extend [this class](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/settings.py#L962). So instead of create  a `SettingsPanel`, create a `CustomSettingsPanel`

Comment: But the problem is that I'll need to do it with a lot of classes, so I just want a way to make python always use `CustomSettingsPanel` and not `SettingsPanel`.

Comment: Why can't you just make `CustomSettingsPanel`, and then refactor your code to use that instead of `SettingsPanel`?

Comment: I did it, but there is a lot of kivy classes using the `SettingsPanel`. So to make each of them use `CustomSettingsPanel`, instead of Kivy default, I needed to inherit each of class and edit the desired methods. So my code huge, just to use this custom class.